# C list->data doesnt show on terminal

Tags: c, list, file, struct, nodes

The console doesnt show the data from my list node.I filled it with chars that i took from a text File.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list_node{
    char data;
    struct list_node* next;
};

typedef struct list_node* node;

node insert_right(node list,char data)
{
    node new_node = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = list->next;
    list->next = new_node;
    return new_node;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fr = fopen("dat1.txt","r");
    node list = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    int i;

    while((i = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){          
            insert_right(list,i);                   
    }
    printf("%c",list->data);
}
```

The main problem i think would be in the insert method.

Comment: You never populate `list->data`, so what exactly do you expect?

Comment: @EugeneSh. populate?

Comment: Assign, set, initialize or whatever synonym you choose..

Comment: @EugeneSh. i initialize it in the insert method

Comment: Show me the line...

Comment: That is true (line 14) `new_node->data = data;`, but when you print, you do not parse the linked list.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc; don't disguise pointers behind typedef (at least not on the code that dereferences them)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Line 12

Comment: I don't see any `list->data = ...` in neither line.

Comment: but new_node->data = data; ?

Comment: So? `new_node` is becoming the next one to the `list`. But you are trying to print `list`.

Comment: No I'm trying to get the first node of the list and this is new_node

Comment: Then your code is not doing what you want. `new_node` is always the second one.

Comment: even with the second one it doesnt go

Comment: What "doesn't go"? If you want to ask a different question - ask it. The problem with this one is clear.

Comment: No it isn't? even if i want to get the data from the second node i don't get anything

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating memory to a node called *list*, but yet you do not initialize any value for **data**, it can be garbage or any character that does not show up in the console.

When you insert a new value, a new node is created and the first one, the "head" so to speak, is still uninitialized even though it is pointing to a second node that has a meaningful data there.

This is your list:

```
// Node Y (X) indicates the Y-th node that has a X value.

Node1 (garbage) -> Node2 (value) -> Node3 (value) -> garbage
```

The last node of your list (which is also the first when you create it) should be pointing to NULL instead of being uninitialized.

I am also pretty sure that your list is poor-implemented because the new elements are always being pointed by list, so you lose track of the ones you created before.

Here is a better version, in my opinion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list_node{
    char data;
    struct list_node* next;
};

typedef struct list_node* node;

void insert_right(node list,char data)
{
    node new_node = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));

    node temp = list;
    // It runs through the list until it reaches the last node
    while(temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next;

    temp->data = data; 
    temp->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fr = fopen("dat1.txt","r");

    // List points to only the first element of the list.
    node list = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    list->next = NULL;
    int i;

    while((i = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){          
            insert_right(list,i);                   
    }
    while(list != NULL) {
      printf("%c",list->data);
      list = list->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am also pretty sure that your list is poor-implement because you will lose track of the first elements of the list" - why? The pointer to the head is maintained.

Comment: @EugeneSh., you are right, I wrongly read the code, will update the answer.

Comment: @Mikael Mello Thanks dude :D

Comment: @Emanuel, I would also recommend to have a different struct for the list and for the element of a list, it helps to understand how it all works. Here it is another "more complete" implementation, it is all in Portuguese but you can understand it by translating a few words. http://pastebin.com/bFZav1Bz

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a linked list. Each node you create needs to point to either NULL or the next node. You were not quite making the links. Also you were not getting the new_node you you were returning. Also when printing out a list you have to go through each node (like an array).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct list_node{
    char data;
    struct list_node* next;
};

typedef struct list_node* node;

node insert_right(node list,char data)
{
    node new_node = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    new_node->data = data;
    list->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fr = fopen("dat1.txt","r");
    node list = (node) malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    int i;
    node next = list;
    while((i = fgetc(fr)) != EOF){           
    next = insert_right(next,i);                   
    }
    node print = list;
    while(print != NULL){
         printf("%c",print->data);
         print = print->next;
    }   
}
```

Comment: i know that but i was too lazy so I wanted to output just one node

Comment: No worries. This is the type of question you get in data structures class, CS1 or something along those lines. Keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_node {
        char data;
        struct list_node* next;
};

int main()
{
        FILE *fr = fopen("dat1.txt","r");
        struct list_node *list = malloc(sizeof(*list)), *pos = list;
        int i;

        while ((i = fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {
                pos->data = i;
                pos->next = malloc(sizeof(*list->next));
                pos = pos->next;
        }

        pos->next = NULL;

        while (list->next) {
                printf("%c ", list->data);

                free(list); /* important!!!! */

                list = list->next;
        }

        putchar('\n');

        return 0;
}
```